# How do you use webdriver to login to auth0 using protractor?

Tags: angular, selenium, webdriver, protractor

Within the protractor.conf.js file of my angular app I have added this code:

```
onPrepare: function() {

     browser.driver.get(
        `https://${auth0Settings.domain}/login?client=${auth0Settings.angularSinglePageAppClientID}&protocol=oauth2`+
        `&redirect_uri=${encodeURI(auth0Settings.loginCallbackUrl)}` +
         `&response_type=${auth0Settings.responseType}` +
        `&scope=openid` +
        `&connection=${auth0Settings.connection}` +
        `&audience=${encodeURI(auth0Settings.portalApiAudience)}` +
        `&auth0Client=aClientIdCopiedFromTheHostedLoginScreenUrl` +
        `&state=aStateBase64StringCopiedFromTheHostedLoginScreenUrl`
     );

     browser.driver.findElement(by.name('email')).sendKeys('anEmail');
     browser.driver.findElement(by.name('password')).sendKeys('aPassword');
     browser.driver.findElement(by.buttonText('Log In')).click();

     // Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
     // For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
     // index.html.
     return browser.driver.wait(function() {
         return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
             return /index/.test(url);
         });
     }, 10000);

     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
}
```

I get an error telling me that webdriver was unable to find the email and password inputs.

I am also a bit dubious as to whether this is the correct approach to ensuring the user is logged in before I run my angular tests, especially since this doesnt appear to spin up a browser and my callback component needs to activate to set the access token. Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please put the related HTML code at here, and have you tried to sleep for seconds to wait page load complete before sendKeys?